# Centering the image in navbar-header / navbar-brand

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first use of bootstrap & i am using the roots theme as a barebones template. 
I have placed an image within the navbar-header element in the header-top-navbar.php 
I also placed it in a div and changed the div class to 'navbar-header' as opposed to the

as shown below.

```
<div class="navbar-brand"> <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo get_theme_root_uri(); ?>/choir/assets/img/harmonics_logo.png"/></a></div>
```

I have no idea how to get this to be central to the page. it's within another div of navbar-header, I have tried float:none and margin: 0 auto; on both to no avail.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

be gentle i's my first post.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8ge4j/)**

**css**

```
.navbar-brand{
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Cool answer, +1. - @Fags - I thought it might not work, but great to see it working in case of OP and you getting paid off for your hard work.

Comment: @NathanLee I think i am not master from you.

Comment: Thnx. for the compliment @Fags :) But I guess I am just a drop of water in a large ocean called CSS and trying to be better by making researches by the day.